# Check empty rows in datatable in Visual Studio 2005, no LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I've uploaded data to a datatable from a excel file. Whats the best way to check empty rows in datatable. NB: Need solution for **Visual Studio 2005**. Cant use linq.

```
foreach (DataRow row in result.Rows)
{
//check if row is empty
//if not continue processing data
//else remove the row from datatable
}
```

*Currently the solution in my mind is inside foreach loop, put another foreach loop and check each column. If all columns are null, remove the row from datatable.*

Is there any other best method. Does the above method takes more time to execute as there is another for each loop. There will be lots of rows in the datatable.

Edited:

I've got one code:

```
private bool checkIfRowEmpty(DataRow row)
    {
        var r = (DataRow)row;
        int emptyCount = 0;
        int itemArrayCount = r.ItemArray.Length;
        foreach (var i in r.ItemArray) if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.ToString())) emptyCount++;
        if (emptyCount == itemArrayCount) return false;
        else return true;
    }
```

Is this okay? Or should I use any solution from below? Which one is good?

Comment: i think two nested loops are simple and performance is also good enough.

Comment: @Jnavero He wants to check each row individually.

Comment: why don't you want to use linq?

Comment: @ZoharPeled linq is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I can think of is the following one:

```
public bool IsRowEmpty(DataRow row)
{
    if (row == null)
        return true;    

    foreach(var value in row.ItemArray)
    {
        if (value != null)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then from your main code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in result.Rows)
{
    if(!IsRowEmpty(row))
    {
        // Row is not empty.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought about. There should be one change I think. It will return false if any column is null. I want to return false only if all columns in a row is null. In the above code I've checked total no of empty rows and rows.count.

Comment: @kingfisher Actually the code works fine as it will return false if at least one of the columns is not null. However I renamed the method so it's easier to understand its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach - to iterate through all rows and all columns

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
List<int> rowsToRemove = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
    foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
    {
        bool skip = false;
        if (row[col] != null)
        {
            //this column is not null, so mark skip flag as true
            skip = true;

        }
        if (skip)
            //this row should be skipped because it has at least one column that isn't null
            break;
        else
            rowsToRemove.Add(i);
            //mark this row's index for deletion
    }
}

//loop through list in reverse order and remove rows by their index
for (int i = rowsToRemove.Count; i > 0; i--)
    table.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello,**

You can simply achive this using DataView : like this -

```
DataView dv = yourTable.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "column_1,column_2";
DataTable dtNew = dv.ToTable(true, "column_1", "column_2",...,"column_n"); // please mention all columns here
dtNew.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```